# Plone bin/instance start and bin/instance restart fail sometimes

Tags: plone

Sometimes it looks like bin/instance start fails for a Plone site. Symptoms

- The site has been running for a while without maintenance
- One runs buildout: `bin/buildout`
- One tries to restart the site using `bin/instance start` or `bin/instance restart`
- The site doesn't start. Nothing is logged to console.
- However, if you run `bin/instance fg` first the site does start

This affects both Plone 3.x and Plone 4.x sites.

Below is a sample how the process goes. You can see that the site doesn't really start despite of giving restart and start, but finally comes up with fg:

```
*************** /PICKED VERSIONS ***************
xxx@yyy:/srv/plone/zzz$ bin/instance restart
.
daemon process restarted, pid=27819
xxx@yyy:/srv/plone/zzz$ bin/instance start

daemon process started, pid=27945
xxx@yyy:/srv/plone/zzz$ bin/instance status
daemon manager not running
xxx@yyy:/srv/plone/zzz$ bin/instance fg
2013-03-08 04:18:11 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Fri Mar  8 04:18:11 2013
    Hostname: 0.0.0.0
    Port: xxxx
```

From log file it looks like it has reached the Zope start. Though both bin/instance status or upstream front end proxy server disagree. You see this in the logs.

```
 2013-03-08T04:19:21 INFO Zope Ready to handle requests
```

Any ideas how to debug this further?

Could it be some sort of race condition / slow start up issue?

Could it be that the process silently dies after `Ready to handle`

Have other people obeserved the same behavior?

Comment: We're seeing similar behaviour here and agree it seems to be some kind of timing problem.
Combined with the fact that restart can crash (!) if a new buildout has taken place in the meantime, we've settled on using `stop; sleep 2; start` which works fine for us.

Answer (score 4):

If `bin/buildout` rebuilds the instance, then it'll also remove and re-build the `parts/instance` directory.

It's that directory that holds a few items that make a `bin/instance restart` *fail*; the daemon process that manages the restart is itself no longer complete.

You need to use `bin/instance stop` to stop the instance *and* the daemonizing process, followed by a `bin/instance start` (which creates a fresh new daemon process).

Comment: ... however the better thing you can do is to use supervirsor, then "bin/supervisorctl restart"

Comment: @keul: sure, but note that potentially `supervisord` could suffer from the same fate. I've not come across it, but I suspect it is possible if you were to store the socket in the `parts` subdirectory you could screw up `supervisord` state just as much. :-)

Comment: Are you sure? I never get this issue using supervisor... but probably because we configure supervisor to perform stop&start when we call restart!

Comment: @keul: sure, I use supervisor the same way; you *have* to, since `supervisord` cannot pull some of the tricks the Zope daemon can do. I am talking about the `supervisord` process state *itself*.

Comment: Any idea how this could be fixed so that bin/restart know its not going to success and aborts? This is very ugly ugly trap for newbies.

Comment: I've not looked into the details for eons now. Possibly, I don't know.