# How to remain running status of zopectl and plone?

Tags: server, plone

Last week my lab's power outage occurred and the web server went out. 
And after then, my webpage doesn't work anymore. My webpage is using plone and zope.

1. So I first went to the directory `/Plone/zinstance/bin`
2. typed `./instance`
3. then did `zopectl start`
4. then I typed `./plonectl start`.

But the problem is the following : everytime I start zopectl and plonectl, the daemon process soon died.

The command line is like this.

[image: plonectl]

[image: zopectl]

I don't know what is the problem and what should I do. Anyone who knows well about plone and zopectl please help me.

Comment: It depends on your installation, but `./instance start` should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plone bin/instance start and bin/instance restart fail sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285766/plone-bin-instance-start-and-bin-instance-restart-fail-sometimes)

Comment: Hi Crystal, welcome to SO! Please throw the error-message into a search engine and see what you can find to avoid duplicate questions, TIA.

Comment: The forum at https://community.plone.org is the best place to ask Plone questions

Answer (score 1):

Try `./instance fg`. If you have an error it will be displayed in the console.

(fg - means running it in the foreground)